# Change resolution screen in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

In Unity3d, I have a panel with a picture. In the corners I have some `InputField`s. When I try to change the aspect ratio or resolution (iPad, iPhone, Free Aspect) the `InputField` does not keep its position, and it doesn't scale with my screen resolution. How I can solve that? I tried anchor, position, and layout elements, but they are not working.

Comment: couldn't be easier. (1) click "add canvas" (be sure to select "scale with screen size" (2) click "add Image" or panel or whatever.  you're done

Comment: Pls search first this is a zillion-times duplicate.  So much material for you https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

Comment: I solved this, with an aspect ratio fitter but have little spaces when change resolution, thanks for help.